Why doesn't my MSI application launch the first time after installation using electron-builder?
I'm building an MSI installer for my Electron application using electron-builder. After installation, when I attempt to launch the application for the first time, it doesn't work (the application either doesn't start or crashes). However, after manually launching the app again, it works without issues.
but it works perfecly in nsis(exe)
{ "build": { "appId": "com.example.myapp", "productName": "My App", "win": { "target":"msi", "msi": { "oneClick": false, "perMachine": false, "createDesktopShortcut": true, "createStartMenuShortcut": true, } } } } 
Why is the app failing to launch the first time after installation, and what can I do to resolve this issue? Is there something specific to the MSI installation process that might be causing this behavior? (it is not crash or broken)

I don't see how the NSIS tag is relevant...
